# i can't add select options to an existing selection field odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

i have declared two selection fields

```
 x = fields.Selection([('x A','x A'),('x B','x B')],string='X')
 y = fields.Selection([('0','0')],string='Y')
```

then i tried to add selection options to **y** field on **onchange**

```
 @api.onchange('x')
    def onchange_x(self):
        self.y = fields.Selection(selection_add = [('y A', 'y A'),('y B', 'y B')])
```

When i select from x selection i get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
> result = request.dispatch()   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
> return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
> return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
> result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 916, in **call**
> return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1346, in call_button
> action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1334, in _call_kw
> return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 464, in call_kw
> result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
> result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom-addons/om_x/models/employee.py", line 34, in
> TestFunction
> self.em_pole = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('Pole A', 'Pole A'), ('Pole B', 'Pole B')], string='Pole')   File
> "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1217, in **set**
> records.write({self.name: write_value})   File "/opt/odoo/addons/hr/models/hr_employee.py", line 317, in write
> res = super(HrEmployeePrivate, self).write(vals)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 323, in write
> result = super(MailThread, self).write(values)   File "/opt/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_activity_mixin.py", line 243, in
> write
> return super(MailActivityMixin, self).write(vals)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3858, in write
> field.write(self, value)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1015, in write
> cache_value = self.convert_to_cache(value, records)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 2534, in convert_to_cache
> raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value)) Exception
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py",
> line 643, in _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
> raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause ValueError: Wrong value for hr.employee.y: <odoo.fields.Selection>

can you help me please .

Comment: This is not possible in Odoo, Try it with the One2many field

Comment: can u explain more pls

Comment: how to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

You should never change selection array in run-time.
Selection array for Selection fields should always be static.
This because odoo in background runs some migrations after installing the module, creating a support postgresql table where selection options are stored.

You can increase (using selection_add) it's options if a different module or models needs them, but still not in run-time. To achieve this, you need first to inherit the respective model, then re-define the field using selection_add argument.

module_1/models/my_model.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  _name = "my.model"
  
  my_selection = fields.Selection(
    selection=[('a', 'A')],
    string="My Selection"
  )
```

module_2/models/my_model.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  _inherit = "my.model"
  
  my_selection = fields.Selection(
    selection_add=[('b', 'B')],
    string="My Selection"
  )
```

For run-time update, your need is to use a Many2one field with a proper domain, which can then be patched via `onchange decorator`.

```
class MyOption(models.Model):
  _name = "my.option"
  
  name = fields.Char()
  filtered = fields.Boolean(default=False)

class MyModel(models.Model):
  _name = "my.model"

  show_filtered_options = fields.Boolean(default=False)
  option_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name="my.option",
    domain="[('filtered', '=', show_filtered_options)]"
  )

  @api.onchange('show_filtered_options')
  def _onchange_show_filtered_options(self):
    self.ensure_one()

    return {'domain': {
        'option_id': [('filtered', '=', self.show_filtered_options)]
      }
    }
```

Finally, populate your options using a data XML file.
Remember to append this in your "data" array inside your module manifest.

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record name="my_option_1" model="my.option">
      <field name="name">Option 1</field>
      <field name="filtered">0</field>
    </record>

    <record name="my_option_2" model="my.option">
      <field name="name">Option 2</field>
      <field name="filtered">1</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

To replicate selection field behaviour in Many2one, you can add `widget="selection"` in your view.

`<field name="option_id" widget="selection" />`